# Passing http.ResponseWriter by value or reference?

Tags: go

Assume I'm having a central method which adds a specific header to the http.ResponseWriter. I don't want to use a HandleFunc wrapper.

I wonder, whether I'd send in the ResponseWriter by reference. So, what would be correct:

```
addHeaders(&w)
```

or

```
addHeaders(w)
```

Asked differently:

```
func addHeaders(w *http.ResponseWriter) {...}
```

or

```
func addHeaders(w http.ResponseWriter) {...}
```

From my understanding, I'd say the first version would be correct, as I don't want to create a copy of ResponseWriter. But I haven't seen any code where ResponseWriter is passed by reference and wonder why.

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`http.ResponseWriter` is an interface. You want to pass its value, since it internally contains a pointer to the actual Writer. You almost never want a pointer to an interface.

Look at what a standard handler func's signature is:

```
func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)
```

Notice that ResponseWriter isn't a pointer.

Comment: Just make it very clear: There is no pass by "reference" in Go. Go has absolutely no notion of "by reference". All one can do is pass a pointer by value. And (almost) all uses of interface do *not* use pointer to interface.

Comment: Note "-er" type names (Reader(At), Writer, Stringer, Locker), or type names describing abstract concepts (crypto.Hash) are often interfaces and thus references, to help spot this in the future. The docs have the final word, of course.